# Default windiw size of Form in c#.net

Tags: c#

I want to open my form with Default window size and ii have two panel inside them LeftPanel and RightPanel.I want those also resize with windows size.How will i do this in Windows C#.net.

Answer (score 2):

Change their Dock property to Fill.  A SplitContainer is a common choice btw, gives the user control over the visible panel size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dock or anchor the panels. You'll find both options in the designer.

Comment: And what about Form opening.I want to open it with the default windows size.